# choose name from dropownlist and associated ID appear in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code for populating a dropdown list with customers name.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating a connection to my database using the connection string
        string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CustomerName from Customer", con);
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CustomerName";

                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
   }
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to be able too; when this name is chosen from the dropdownlist box , the associated customer ID will appear in a textbox.

thanks!

Comment: you'll need an event handler on the dropdownlist1 selectedindexchanged event

Comment: @Ctznkane525 i have edited the code and put this in but unsure of the code that would be placed inside this.

Comment: In that method assign your text box text property the selectedvalue of the dripdownlist

Answer (score -1):

It should be as simple as this, by the looks of it:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
}
```

Assuming you have a textbox whose ID is `TextBox1`.

Alternatively if you want to display the text from the dropdown list (as opposed to the ID value), then simply:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
}
```